# What is wrong with creating a class and defining a connection in python

Tags: python, redis

I have created a class in python, and calling the `__init__` variables in class methods. 
Few of the init variables give error.

Following is the class :

```
class MyRedisClass(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10
    # the line below gives an error - global name 'pool' is not defined
    # if the below line is commented, I can get the value of DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE inside the some_function
    self.pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='XXX.XXX.XX.XX', port=XXXX, db=0) 
    self.redis_connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)

  def some_function(self, some_data):
    print self.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
    pipeline = self.redis_connection.pipeline()
    it = iter(some_data)
    for member, score in zip(it, it):
        pipeline.zadd(leaderboard_name, member, score)
    pipeline.execute()
```

In the terminal I create an instance of class as follows -

```
mklass = MyRedisClass()
mklass.some_function(['a', 1])
```

as pointed out I get an error - `global name 'pool' is not defined`

What is wrong with the above class declaration?

Why am I getting NameError, at the place when I am declaring pool?

For a better class definition, do I need to do some `super` or `classmethod`?

Answer (score 5):

You access `pool` as `self.pool` instead of just pool:

```
self.redis_connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=self.pool)
```